Norm and residue field algebraically closed
$K$ is a dv field with residue field algebraically closed and $L$ a finite extension
I read as "well known" that the norme is onto on units.
I known this result for unramified extension but i cannot find a proof in my case.
I threw a glance in Serre's book but the results are so general and so complicated that i was unable to find my result.
I don't need any result about  higher units : $N(U_L^n) $, Just $N(U_L)=U_K$.
Can someone give à hint, a proof, a link...
Thank you

Hmm, if the extension is of degree $n$ then the norm just acts as $n$-th power on the base field $K$, and I would think the unit group of that should be $n$-divisible because that of the residue field is, via some Hensel-style argument, at least if the residue characteristic does not divide $n$. On the other hand, for $n=p$ and $K=\bar{\mathbb F}_p((T))$, say, one does need more than $U_K$ to get the full image. I don't see a general argument right away.
